# button-add information in the table

Tags: c#

```
private void btnDodaj_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        if (txtIme.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unesite ime kandidata.");
            return;
        }
        if (txtPrezime.Text=="")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unesite prezime kandidata.");
            return;
        }
        if (numUspeh.Value==0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unesite uspeh kandidata iz srednje skole.");
            return;
        }
        if(numPoeni.Value==0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unesite broj poena kandidata osvojenih na prijemnom.");
            return;
        }

        dtpDatumRodj.Value = DateTime.Now;
        OleDbConnection konekcija = new OleDbConnection(constring);
        konekcija.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = konekcija;

cmd.CommandText = String.Format(
"INSERT INTO Kandidati(Ime,Prezime,DatumRodjenja,UspehSkola,PoeniPrijemni) VALUES   ('{0}' ,'{1}' , '{2}' , '{3}' , '{4}' )" 
,txtIme.Text,txtPrezime.Text,dtpDatumRodj.Value,numUspeh.Value,numPoeni.Value);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        konekcija.Close();
        ds.Clear();
        da.Fill(ds);
```

The exception is thrown when i click on the button "btnDodaj(btnAdd)" on the line

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and it says:

> The changes you requested to the table were not successful because
>   they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or
>   relationship.Change the data in the field or fields that contain
>   duplicate data, remove the index, or redefine the index to permit
>   duplicate entries and try again.

How can i correct this?

Comment: your error is pretty much self explanatory

Comment: At least one of your parameters appears to be text. This leaves you open to SQL injection; I would strongly recommend you move to using parameterised queries.

Comment: Do you have a primary key column on your update statement ?

Comment: Without seeing your table structure it's impossible to say, but if you're not populating your primary key check that auto-increment is switched on.

Comment: You are attempting to, as the error message explains, insert a duplicate key, are they auto generated by the DB, or generate a unique one

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the taking the following steps:

1. add a unique id column to your table and set it as the primary key
2. assign a GUID number to that property you can see code for that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx)

Let me know if that fixed your problem
Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

> create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship

From error message it is evident that the data that you are trying to insert contains a primary key that is already present in the database. And as insertion will create a duplicate key , **which is not permitted** hence the error.

**Solution:** You should first check if the primary key of the data that you are trying to insert is already present than you should update it rather than inserting a new one. Something like

```
IF EXISTS( Select 'x' from Kandidati WHERE YOurPrimaryKey = keyyouarepassing)
BEGIN
    UPDATE Kandidati 
    values
    ....
    WHERE
    YOurPrimaryKey = keyyouarepassing
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   INSERT into Kandidati ....
END
```